# Package Vuejs application as a library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a single page Vue application and want to package it as a library in order to use components in an other server side application. Is their a guide or help how to do this ? Can i reuse directly the generated packages ? One of the issue is that the vue compiler is not included also how to use plug-ins like vuetify and vuex etc. Any help or guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can read about packaging vue components for npm [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html) if that is what you mean